# Clip up numbers bigger than maximum

Tags: list, functional-programming, sml

I have this function:

```
fun min x y = if x >= y then y else x
```

and I need to use this function (as a partial application) and make function clipupdown with arguments number and list, where number represents the minimal number that should exist in that list and all numbers lower than min should be set to that minimal number. For example when I call:

```
clipdown 10 [1,11,21,4,6,7,12]
```

I should get

```
[10,11,21,10,10,10,12]
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 3):

> Any hints?

1. What do you get when you call `min` (edit: or, actually `max`) with only one element?

   ```
   min 10
   ```
2. how do you map a function over a list?

Comment: You actually need to use the "max" function. As he's just asking for hints, I guess this answer shouldn't be downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

```
fun clipdown lowest numbers = map (max lowest) numbers
```

You have to use max, instead of min. Whenever the program finds a number below the minimum, it should choose the minimum (which is greater than the encountered number). So you need to choose the max value.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Int.min` and `Int.max` already exist, but take tuples, you could write a function

```
fun curry f x y = f (x, y)
```

and use this like `map o curry Int.max` to get `clipdown`.

Similarly you could get `clipup` with `map o curry Int.min`.

You might also get `clipupdown` by composing both like

```
fun clipupdown lower higher = clipdown lower o clipup higher
```

But you could also use that *(map f) ∘ (map g) = map (f ∘ g)*:

```
fun clipupdown lower higher = map (curry Int.max lower o curry Int.min higher)
```

This is called [*map fusion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)#Optimizations).